# Henry's Law - When scuba diving, why is breathing pure $\rm O_2$ not the same as going to outer space?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, physical-chemistry, gas, diffusion

#### In Short

I had a discussion with my dive instructor the other day. He said that for "decompression dives" you can cut down decompression time to 1/3 if you switch to pure $\rm O_2$ at 6m.

This got me thinking, why isn't breathing pure $\rm O_2$ at 6m (or any depth really) the same as going to "outer space" directly w.r.t. gas diffusion out of a substance?

#### Picture

[image]

#### Some background

To what I understand the main reason we have to do decompression stops is because $\rm N_2$ gets at depth dissolved in various tissues **because**(?) when descending  the partial pressure of the gas I breathe is now higher than the partial pressure of the gas in, say, my fatty tissue.

Now when I ascend the partial pressure of my breathing gas gets lower again, which means my "saturated tissue" has a higher partial pressure and starts to diffuse out, until after some time I finally exhale it.

If that happens to fast bubbles can form in my body, causing all sorts of bad things.

But with this model in mind, why isn't switching to pure $\rm O_2$ at 6m now the same as just catapulting me to space, or even just better than going to the surface where I'd have AT LEAST 0.78 bar partial pressure nitrogen, which would have a less severe gradient.

**Edit** - There might be additional medical reasons, but for the sake of argument I'd be interested to hear an answer if we replace the diver with a sponge or whipped cream in a plastic bag.

**Edit 2** - The more I think about it, I think this question really boils down to my (lack of) understanding of [Henry's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry%27s_law)

Comment: The bubbles are problem in the small blood vessels, when they appear in the blood due to total pressure of the blood decreasing; exhaling may intensify this, but even without exhaling total pressure decreases due to ascent.

Comment: It is hard to understand the question - obviously, being under pressure 1.6bar is very different than being in space at pressure lower than 1bar.

Comment: > obviously, being under pressure 1.6bar is very different than being in space 
That is my question, is it obvious? Let's say $10g$ of $N_2$ in $1kg$ of whipped cream in ambient air is the saturation limit. Now I place the cream in pure $O_2$, what does the $N_2$ do (and why)? Similarly, I place the cream in a vacuum, what does the $N_2$ do (and why), and why does it differ or not between these two experiments?

Comment: What the bubbles of $\text{N}_2$ will do depends on total pressure outside the bubbles, not so much on chemical composition of the surrounding atmosphere, I think. If total pressure is high enough, they are quite stable as they are. If the pressure is low, they expand. If the pressure is extremely low, the bubbles may cease to exist, as they expand into vacuum and pop.

Comment: > _depends on total pressure outside the bubbles, not so much on chemical composition of the surrounding atmosphere_
But what about [Henry's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry%27s_law), which states that the amount of gas dissolved is proportional to the _partial pressure_ above the medium?

Comment: Henry's law is about amount of dissolved gas in a liquid (no bubbles). When the cream in the can expands into the atmosphere, the gas in the cream is no longer completely dissolved, but forms bubbles. Stability of these bubbles is strongly influenced by total pressure, not partial pressure.